# Inserting a BLOB data into object type - Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, insert, blob, object-type

I'm using the following code to create a type INFOS as object :

```
 create or replace TYPE INFOS AS OBJECT
 (
    NAME VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
    PICTURE BLOB
 )
```

and the table CLIENT that use the type INFOS:

```
create table client
(
    ID_CLIENT int not null primary key,
    INFORMATIONS INFOS
)
```

code inserting :

```
insert into client values(1,INFOS('john',EMPTY_BLOB()))
```

I could not return the column INFO.PICTURE into a variable.

so, how I can insert a BLOB data into this table.

Comment: `insert into CLIENT values (1, infos('John', your_blob_locator));`

Comment: but how i can return the INFOS.PICTURE into A VARIABLE to make a commit ?

Comment: Use `DBMS_LOB` package.

Comment: I tried  to do this with DBMS_LOB, but it doesn't work, can you show me an example ? thank you EgorSkriptunoff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
declare
  i infos;
  b blob;
begin
  insert 
    into client 
    values(1, INFOS('John', EMPTY_BLOB()))
    returning informations into i;
  b := i.picture;
  -- You can use b here
end;
```